# how to stop text-speech when android app closed by user

Tags: android

I'm looking for all kind of functions like onDestroy . but i'm exactly looking for a function that runs when app closed by user. i'm using text-speech in my application, but while it's speaking, if user close app(no matter how, force stop, or exit button in app , ...) it will keep speaking. is there any specific function for this?

Thanks in advance

Attirant

code:

```
private boolean t1State = false;
private TextToSpeech t1;

private void start_voice(String text)
{
    t1=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
        }
    });
    String msg = "Voice Started";
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    t1.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    t1State = true;
}
private void stop_voice()
{
    String msg;
    if(t1 !=null) {
        t1.stop();
    }
    msg = "Voice has been Stopped";
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    t1State = false;
}
```

Comment: Are you using service?

Comment: no, there's no services in app

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: i shared it now,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop `TextToSpeech` in `OnPause()` of the `Activity`. Since `OnPause()` will be called for sure, everytime the user exit the screen, whereas `onDestroy()`/ `onStop()` is not guaranteed to call like that.

```
 TextToSpeech t1 =new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
     @Override
     public void onInit(int status) {

     }
  });
 public void onPause(){
      if(t1 !=null){
         t1.stop();
         t1.shutdown();
      }
      super.onPause();
   }
```

Comment: what you're trying to say is, onPause will be called , as soon as user close app?